# Can a website be full amp and still have good results on seo?

Tags: seo, amp, laravel

I am very new to development, learning just to make a project more efficient now, despite having a dream to be a developer I am too old to change from where I am.

I had some content written on wordpress and was needing more tools to make available for my readers, so I decide to remake it 100% under laravel. Since I am very noob I was looking for stuff that I wanted to add and was pushing to have some webstories on my new website and because of that I picked amp to work as the frontend.

My actual website is l96.app and the new one is running at lab.l06.app (I will delete the old one when this one is ready)

My question now is: Is it possible to have a website without a normal front end and just amp pages? Will it harm my SEO using pure amp pages or do I need normal ones also, for better indexation?

I need helps and tips about having a full amp website and optimization or exemples about how to do or do not it.

Answer (score -1):

As such, SEO doesn't care about the technology you use to create the web pages. What matters is

- HTML it sees and its correctness and logic
- Value of some tags
- Content and its relevancy